# WordPress - embedding content slider (easiest way)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, embed

I'm really not sure what's wrong. I doubt this is a problem many would come across as it's a stupid way of doing it. I have searched a while for an answer but either couldn't find one or it was too advanced for me to understand (PHP mixed with WordPress code)

My knowledge of PHP is zero. HTML and CSS are moderate.

I've made a content slider out of a jQuery plugin (not a WordPress one), which you can see here: http://invigoratebusiness.com/ax1/Slider.html

I have a WordPress site that I want to add the slider too, but I want to do it as quick and painlessly as possible. I thought to use iframes or embed.

Here's how I embedded it:

```
<embed src="http://invigoratebusiness.com/ax1/Slider.html" width="960" height="590">
```

have also added  scrolling="no" but to no avail

I added this to WordPress via the HTML page editor (opposed to the "visual" one).

Now the problems are:

[1] There's too much white space above or below it. Once it's added to WordPress and if i shrink the "height="590" (the height of the slider is less like  450 - 500 px) in the embed code it unnecessarily adds a scroll bar and still has too much white space.

Ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdpuO.png

[2] I've noticed it's not showing up in Chrome once added to WordPress either (works in Safari, Opera and didn't test Moz) and the slider itself works fine when it's **not embedded** in Chrome.

Hope I've explained it well! Wasn't very easy to. I would really appreciate some help or advice... or another method (if easy) the slider includes jQuery, a separate CSS file and HTML. the slider is based on SudoSlider:

```
webbies.dk/SudoSlider/
```

Thanks heaps for you time!

Comment: Hi. Can you please show us some code or preferably the URL so we can try to see what's happened.

Comment: Hello here's all the code http://invigoratebusiness.com/demo/index.html and the embed code i used is above in the main description. thanks

Comment: Not sure I see what the problem is. http://invigoratebusiness.com/ax1/Slider.html shows (via Firebug or IE's F12) that there are no excessive margins above or below the slider and you seem to have removed the "communication" section included in your example image.

Comment: the example image shows the problem on the actual site (the screen shot just cuts it off) the  invigoratebusiness.com/ax1/Slider.html  is the slider i need to insert into the main wordpress page, but ever time i do theres a massive gap. the real site with to problem is here http://goo.gl/4FnRs by the way thanks for your help and interest so far :D

Comment: Well? Did my answer do it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `embed` to `iframe`, and your height is way off too. It should be:

```
<iframe width="960" height="460" src="http://invigoratebusiness.com/ax1/Slider.html">
```

Works perfect for me now.

Comment: Yay working for me too! thanks heaps ahh that's such a relief! thanks so much for your help, very much appreciated!